# Like button likes all posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've implemented a like/unlike function in my app. On the show page for an item, you can like/unlike without any issues. On a user's profile page though, where it lists all the foods they've uploaded, I have two issues: First, when I click the like button for one food, it triggers it for every food and then the button text under every food says "unlike this food", instead of only having the button text change for just the food that was clicked on. The like gets saved to the db for the correct food, but obviously I don't want the button text to change for foods that I haven't liked. Second, when I try to like a different food on the page without refreshing, the liked gets saved in the db as the original food that I clicked on, instead of the one I actually clicked on.

```
users.show.html.erb

<% @user.foods.each do |food| %>
    <div class="row col-md-12">
        <div class="food col-md-4">
            <h3 class="title"><%= link_to food.title.capitalize, food_path(food.id) %></h3>
            <%= link_to (image_tag (food.image.url)), food_path(food.id) %>
            <%= render 'shared/vote_form', :food => food %>

            <%= link_to pluralize(food.votes.count, "person"), user_votes_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :food_id => food.id) %> <%= food.votes.count == 1 ? 'wants' : 'want' %> to gobble this
        </div>

        <div class="description col-md-6">
        <% if @user.id == current_user.id %>

                <% if food.description.length == 0 %>
                    <p><%= link_to "Add Description", edit_food_path(food) %></p>   
                <% else %>
                    <p><%= food.description %><p>
            <p><%= link_to "Edit Description", edit_food_path(food) %></p>
                <% end %>

          <% if food.recipe.length == 0 %>
            <p><%= link_to "Add Recipe", edit_food_path(food) %></p>
          <% end %>

        <% else %>

          <% if food.description.length == 0 %>
            <p>No Description</p> 
          <% else %>
            <p><%= food.description %><p>
          <% end %>

          <% if food.recipe.length == 0 %>
            <p>No Recipe</p>
          <% else %>
            <p><%= link_to "View Recipe", food_path(food) %></p>  
          <% end %>

        <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

---

votes controller

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @votes = Food.find(params[:food_id]).votes
  end

  def new
    @vote = current_user.votes.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @vote = current_user.votes.build(vote_params)


    if @vote.save!
      @food = @vote.food
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back, notice: "Liked!"}
        format.js  
      end

      puts @vote.food.id
    else
      puts "No"
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = current_user
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
    @food = @vote.food

    if @vote.destroy!
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back, notice: "Unliked!"}
        format.js 
      end
    else
      puts "NOOOOOO"
    end
  end

  private

  def vote_params
    params.require(:vote).permit(:food_id)
  end
end
```

---

```
vote partial

<% unless current_user.votes.pluck(:food_id).include?(food.id) %>
    <%= button_to "Like This Food", user_votes_path(current_user, { vote: { food_id: food.id } }), :remote => true %>
<% else %>
    <% vote = food.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first %>
    <%= button_to "Unlike This Food", user_vote_path(current_user, vote), :remote => true, method: "delete" %>
<% end %>
```

---

```
create.js.erb

$('.button_to').replaceWith("<%= j (render :partial => 'shared/vote_form', :locals => { :food => @food, :food_id => @food.id }) %>");
```

---

```
destroy.js.erb

$('.button_to').replaceWith("<%= j (render :partial => 'shared/vote_form', :locals => { :food => @food }) %>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your `create.js.erb` (`destroy.js.erb` has the same problem). You use select *all* elements with the class `button_to` - that is all buttons on the page. Then you call `replaceWith` that replaces *all* these buttons with the button provided as the argument. The result is that all buttons get replaced with the like button corresponding to the food you just liked. This is responsible for affecting all buttons on the page and making them refer the food you liked first.

The solution is to add an `id` attribute to the buttons that would include the ID of the food the button pertains to. For example, if `Food` with ID 1 is `Lettuce` then you need to add `id="like-1"` to the button and change `$('.button_to')` to `$("#like-1")`.

Comment: hmm makes sense. Instead of adding IDs, would I be able to add a .click function to what I have now and then utilize $(this) ?

Comment: Also, if a user has uploaded a lot of foods, I'm not sure how to dynamically create button ids like $("#like-1") in the .js.erb files

Comment: Just add `id: "food-#{@food.id}"` as an argument to `button_to`. This will add the IDs on the generated elements. In your `js.erb` files, use `$('#food-<%= @food.id %>')` instead of `$(.button_to')`. Regarding `this` - you could specify `data-like` and `data-unlike` attributes and set them to the food ID. You could then add an event handler on the container that would match clicks on buttons with these attributes, fire a request and update the page based on the response. It'll be more complicated though.